# Will arguments make an object non-collectible by JavaScript GC?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

```
var person = {
    name: 'John'
};

function Pet1(person) {
    var owner = person.name;
    this.showOwner = function() {
        alert(owner);
    }
}

function Pet2(person) {
    this.showOwner = function() {
        alert(person.name);
    }
}

var pets = [new Pet1(person), new Pet2(person)];

...

pets.splice(0, 1);
pets.splice(0, 1);
```

Which code above prevent's JS GC to not collect instances of Pet1 and Pet2 when they go out of scope or when there are no more references to either. What I know is Pet2 but don't you think Pet1 also prevents JS GC?

Comment: If those are supposed to be constructors then what would be best in this case is putting the method into the `prototype` thus sharing it across instances, otherwise you're duplicating this method for every instance as a different function that has to be GC'ed AFAIK. I could be wrong...

Comment: yup, but what I am asking is will the person (it's global in this case) variable prevent instances of Pet1 and Pet2 to be garbage collected (if out of scope and no more references)?

Comment: ...it sounds like you're thinking about that backwards @Jojo. Pet1 and Pet2 instances could be collected at any time, here, because they aren't depended on by other code.  Pet2 instances depend on a Person. Therefore, any instance of a Person, which is referenced inside of a Pet2 will be unavailable for collection, until that Pet2 is collected. But that's Person GC and not Pet2 GC.

Comment: Nothing prevents the GC not to collect the instances, it depends on the implementation of the GC when it wants to (try to) collect them. If you are asking about something preventing the collection, there is nothing after you've spliced the references to them out of the array. Or did I misunderstood your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is "it depends".

In terms of modern engines, if `person` were removed from everywhere else in the system, it could still be collected, even if it was mentioned in the argument, because despite being inside the closure, it's never referenced ever again, from any method which is publicly available.

Therefore, engines which support removing vestigial pieces of a scope could easily run GC on that object.

The question, then, is which engines do that, and which versions of those engines do so?
I'm not sure of the answer to that.

Just that it's possible, but could remain resident in memory on older or lesser JS engines.

### EDIT

Think of it like this: `var pet1 = new Pet1(person);` 
Pet1 used person to set values for pet1.
person doesn't know a thing about pet1.

`var pet2 = new Pet2(person);`
pet2 has a function which looks for person, to read a value.
So even if person is never mentioned in the code again, it can't be removed, because pet2 might call a function which needs to find person...
person still has no clue what a pet2 is.

When pet2 isn't needed anymore, and when it's removed from the array above, and when every single variable/object-property/array-index which referenced it has its references removed, including removing functions which were created inside of a scope that it exists in, and have references to it, somehow, it can be removed, because NO OTHER CODE is looking for/hanging onto pet2.

Once pet2 is gone, person isn't used anywhere else, anymore.
Therefore, person can be marked for collection.

GC is all about what has access to a thing.
If other things are still talking about the object, then the object is not allowed to be removed.
An instance could depend on 50 arguments, and have references to 120 other outside objects, but that instance could still be collected if nobody else cares about *it*.

Comment: If person is still alive but the elements of the arrays are all spliced (no more references to Pet1 and Pet2), will the instances of the 'former' array elements (Pet1 and Pet2) be GCed? I am beginning to think so based on searching for answers, but I hope someone can still clarify this and hopefully with a WHY... :D

Comment: @Jojo Yes they will (or at least, will be earmarked for collection, versus being forcibly deleted at that time, depending on GC-method). P1 and P2 are not used by any other code. Which means that the only place they exist has just gotten rid of them... ...which means that they can be collected.  But like I said, `person` can't be earmarked for collection until after P2 is removed, because P2 depends on person existing.

Comment: Think of it like this: `var pet1 = new Pet1(person);` Pet1 used person to set values for pet1. person doesn't know a thing about `pet1`. `var pet2 = new Pet2(person);` pet2 has a function which looks for person, to read a value. So even if person is never mentioned in the code again, it can't be removed, because `pet2` might call a function which needs to find `person`...  `person` still has no clue what a `pet2` is. When `pet2` isn't needed anymore, it can be removed, because NO OTHER CODE is looking for/hanging onto `pet2`. Once `pet2` is gone, `person` isn't used anywhere else, anymore.

Comment: that's the 'assurance' that I'm looking for :), add that to your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Jojo As you wish.  The post has been edited.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

On the question from your comment:

> will the person (it's global in this case) variable prevent instances of Pet1 and Pet2 to be garbage collected (if out of scope and no more references)

No, why should it? `person` does not reference the Pet instances, it's the other way round. Once you have removed the references to the Pet instances from the `pets` array, there is nothing that prevents the GC to collect them (assuming your "`...`" code does not create other references to `pets[0]` or `pets[1]`).